# Web forms for 100-200k concurrent users with node.js

Tags: node.js, scalability

I need to create a web form to collect user data (survey) that is expected to peak at 100-200k concurrent users, maybe more. I'm more experienced with Java & PHP solutions with RDBMS for persistence, and with those platforms I'd need a ton of VMs and serious hardware load distribution to handle this kind of traffic.

Since this might not be cost effective, I'm flirting with the idea of node.js and possibly a message queue or a NoSQL data store.

Has anyone faced this problem and tried a similar solution?

Comment: I don't think concurrent users is the statistic you need, unless you need to store session data (which would sting). Do you have an idea what the peak page views and form submits per second might be?

Comment: 100-200k concurrent users sounds outrageously high. Is that connections/sec, how many users will use the survey over a period of time or some other metric?

Comment: It is also doable with e.g. Java 7 and Tomcat 7. Some Telecom companies run 80k+ concurrent devices per host. But it does require quite a bit of tuning and thinking. Also, would involve AsyncContext, NIO etc. Unload all static resources to CDN, increase ulimits and max file handles in OS and most probably you will be limited by local network infrastructure, not your host. Also, it is important to get testing infrastructure first, and start small and simple - like echo service for 50k users. Node.js is just as fine, and needs the same approach.

Answer (score 2):

Node.js would be the right choice for this job. Node.js allocates only a small heap per connection and this is much faster than creating a thread for each client connection, plus Node.js is non-blocking and event oriented.

Answer (score 0):

A cloud solution seems viable for this specific problem.

AWS offers 'server less backends', you can for example let the processing of the web form handle by AWS's 'api gateway' where you can upload your node.js script that processes the data. With API gateway you do not need to bother with servers or horizontal scaling; basically you pay a small amount for execution time. Then you can insert the data in a nosql database such as dynamodb which can be scaled to almost any arbitrary write operations per second.

This is how I'd handle it. For the amount of concurrency, you can easily down and upscale and not be bothered by structural infrastructural costs; maybe other cloud providers provide similar functionality but I have no experience with that.